# Check col1 if duplicate then check col2 if distinct

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hey guys I've been struggling to get a simple query done in SnowFlake.
A sample of the data is explained below,

| Number | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2559 | 23 |
| 2559 | 33 |
| 2559 | 55 |
| 2550 | 89 |
| 2499 | 14 |
| 2499 | 14 |

Based on the table above I would like to create a column that checks if (column Number) have duplicated values if yes; then check (column ID) if the values associated with that Number were duplicated or distinct. If values were duplicated then return 0 if values were distinct then return 1.

The desired outcome is as follows,

| Number | ID | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2559 | 23 | 1 |
| 2559 | 33 | 1 |
| 2559 | 55 | 1 |
| 2550 | 89 | 0 |
| 2499 | 14 | 0 |
| 2499 | 14 | 0 |

and the last outcome should be on the Number column level (group by) and would be like the following table,

| Number | Check |
| --- | --- |
| 2559 | 1 |
| 2550 | 0 |
| 2499 | 0 |

Any suggestions are appreciated.

---

Edited tables

The scenario has changed based on new requirements

The original table have two IDs (ID1 and ID2) and those IDs must be linked to two different tables T-ID1 and T-ID2.

| Number | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2559 | 23 | null |
| 2559 | 33 | null |
| 2559 | 55 | null |
| 2550 | 89 | null |
| 2499 | 14 | null |
| 2499 | 14 | null |
| 2498 | null | 14 |
| 2498 | null | 50 |
| 2498 | null | null |

So the idea is if Number has duplicated IDs (in ID1 or ID2) then return 1, if Number has unique ID (in ID1 or ID2) then return ID1 or ID2. if Number have null values for ID1 and ID2 then ignore the entire row.

This is the query I am using - everything works based on solution provided below, but I am getting nulls along with ID values.

ID1 is linked to Supplier_ID_Ekuep and ID2 is linked to Supplier_ID_Qava.

```
select wbd.WAYBILL_ID, sup.WAYBILL_NO,
       sup.Supplier_ID_Qava, supq.Supplier_Qava, supq.Supllier_City_Qava, supq.Supplier_Qava_Add,
       sup.Supplier_ID_Ekuep, supc.Supplier_Ekuep, supc.Supllier_City_Ekuep, supc.Supplier_Ekuep_Add
from WAYBILL_PRODUCTS wbd
left join (select wb.WAYBILL_ID, ow.WAYBILL_NO,
       case when mult.multi_supp_qava = 1 then '1'
            when mult.multi_supp_qava = 0 then op.ID_Supplier_Qava
            else null end as Supplier_ID_Qava,
       case when mult.multi_supp_ekuep = 1 then '1'
            when mult.multi_supp_ekuep = 0 then op.ID_Supplier_Ekuep
            else null end as Supplier_ID_Ekuep
from WAYBILL_PRODUCTS wb
left join (select ID, ORDER_ID, WAYBILL_NO from ORDER_WAYBILLS) ow on wb.WAYBILL_ID = ow.id
left join (select opr.ID_ORDER, opr.ID_PRODUCT, ss.ID_Supplier_Ekuep, ss.ID_Supplier_Qava
          from ORDER_PRODUCTS opr
left join (select s.id, supc.*, supq.*
          from SUPPLIERS s
left join (select ID_SUPPLIER as ID_Supplier_Ekuep
from EKUEP_KSA_EKUEP_STAGING.PS_SUPPLIER where USED_SUPPLIER_ID is null) supc on supc.ID_Supplier_Ekuep = s.ID_SUPPLIER and s.STORE_ID = 1
left join (select ID_SUPPLIER as ID_Supplier_Qava
from QAVASHOP_KSA_QAVAISH_MAINSHOP.PS_SUPPLIER where USED_SUPPLIER_ID is null) supq on supq.ID_Supplier_Qava = s.ID_SUPPLIER and s.STORE_ID = 2) ss on opr.SUPPLIER_ID = ss.ID
group by opr.ID_ORDER, opr.ID_PRODUCT, ss.ID_Supplier_Ekuep, ss.ID_Supplier_Qava) op on op.ID_PRODUCT = wb.PRODUCT_ID and op.ID_ORDER = ow.ORDER_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
left join (select wb.WAYBILL_ID, ow.WAYBILL_NO,
       (count(distinct op.ID_Supplier_Qava) > 1)::int as multi_supp_qava,
       (count(distinct op.ID_Supplier_Ekuep) > 1)::int as multi_supp_ekuep
from WAYBILL_PRODUCTS wb
left join (select ID, ORDER_ID, WAYBILL_NO from ORDER_WAYBILLS) ow on wb.WAYBILL_ID = ow.id
left join (select opr.ID_ORDER, opr.ID_PRODUCT, ss.ID_Supplier_Ekuep, ss.ID_Supplier_Qava
          from ORDER_PRODUCTS opr
left join (select s.id, supc.ID_Supplier_Ekuep, supq.ID_Supplier_Qava
          from SUPPLIERS s
left join (select ID_SUPPLIER as ID_Supplier_Ekuep
from EKUEP_KSA_EKUEP_STAGING.PS_SUPPLIER where USED_SUPPLIER_ID is null) supc on supc.ID_Supplier_Ekuep = s.ID_SUPPLIER and s.STORE_ID = 1
left join (select ID_SUPPLIER as ID_Supplier_Qava
from QAVASHOP_KSA_QAVAISH_MAINSHOP.PS_SUPPLIER where USED_SUPPLIER_ID is null) supq on supq.ID_Supplier_Qava = s.ID_SUPPLIER and s.STORE_ID = 2
    ) ss on opr.SUPPLIER_ID = ss.ID
group by opr.ID_ORDER, opr.ID_PRODUCT, ss.ID_Supplier_Ekuep, ss.ID_Supplier_Qava) op on op.ID_PRODUCT = wb.PRODUCT_ID and op.ID_ORDER = ow.ORDER_ID
where _FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
group by wb.WAYBILL_ID, ow.WAYBILL_NO) mult on mult.WAYBILL_NO = ow.WAYBILL_NO
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
group by wb.WAYBILL_ID, ow.WAYBILL_NO, mult.multi_supp_qava, mult.multi_supp_ekuep, op.ID_Supplier_Qava, op.ID_Supplier_Ekuep) sup on wbd.WAYBILL_ID = sup.WAYBILL_ID

left join
(select ps.ID_SUPPLIER                  as ID_Supplier_Qava,
        ps.name                         as Supplier_Qava,
        listagg(distinct pa.CITY, ', ') as Supllier_City_Qava,
        ps.DATE_ADD                     as Supplier_Qava_Add
from QAVASHOP_KSA_QAVAISH_MAINSHOP.PS_SUPPLIER ps
left join (select * from QAVASHOP_KSA_QAVAISH_MAINSHOP.PS_ADDRESS) pa on pa.ID_SUPPLIER = ps.ID_SUPPLIER and pa._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
where ps.USED_SUPPLIER_ID is null and ps._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
group by ID_Supplier_Qava, Supplier_Qava, Supplier_Qava_Add) supq on supq.ID_Supplier_Qava = sup.Supplier_ID_Qava

left join
(select ps.ID_SUPPLIER                  as ID_Supplier_Ekuep,
        ps.name                         as Supplier_Ekuep,
        listagg(distinct pa.CITY, ', ') as Supllier_City_Ekuep,
        ps.DATE_ADD                     as Supplier_Ekuep_Add
from EKUEP_KSA_EKUEP_STAGING.PS_SUPPLIER ps
left join (select * from EKUEP_KSA_EKUEP_STAGING.PS_ADDRESS) pa on pa.ID_SUPPLIER = ps.ID_SUPPLIER and pa._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
where ps.USED_SUPPLIER_ID is null and ps._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
group by ID_Supplier_Ekuep, Supplier_Ekuep, Supplier_Ekuep_Add) supc on supc.ID_Supplier_Ekuep = sup.Supplier_ID_Ekuep
where _FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
group by wbd.WAYBILL_ID, sup.WAYBILL_NO,
       sup.Supplier_ID_Qava, supq.Supplier_Qava, supq.Supllier_City_Qava, supq.Supplier_Qava_Add,
       sup.Supplier_ID_Ekuep, supc.Supplier_Ekuep, supc.Supllier_City_Ekuep, supc.Supplier_Ekuep_Add
```

The output I am getting for Waybill_No = 43265104 is as follows, I just want to get rid of the null row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    left join (
        select 
            ID, 
            ORDER_ID, 
            WAYBILL_NO 
        from ORDER_WAYBILLS
    ) ow 
        on wb.WAYBILL_ID = ow.id
```

should just be:

```
    LEFT JOIN order_waybills AS ow
        ON wb.waybill_id = ow.id
```

### Gaint Refactoing Starts Here

So I start refactoring this SQL, the first part was to ignore my prior "this could be simpler" and move that into a CTE `ob_cte`, so it was "just simple" then I notice the first two sections had large block you noted as `op` that where the same, so that becomes a CTE `op_cte` also then that gives us:

```
WITH ob_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        order_id, 
        waybill_no 
    FROM order_waybills
), op_etc AS (
    SELECT 
        opr.id_order,
        opr.id_product,
        ss.id_supplier_ekuep,
        ss.id_supplier_qava
    FROM order_products AS opr
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            s.id, 
            supc.id_supplier_ekuep, 
            supq.id_supplier_qava
        FROM suppliers AS s
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id_supplier AS id_supplier_ekuep
            FROM ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier 
            WHERE used_supplier_id IS NULL
        ) AS supc 
            ON supc.id_supplier_ekuep = s.id_supplier 
                AND s.store_id = 1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id_supplier AS id_supplier_qava
            FROM qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_supplier 
            WHERE used_supplier_id IS NULL
        ) AS supq 
            ON supq.id_supplier_qava = s.id_supplier
                AND s.store_id = 2
    ) AS ss 
        ON opr.SUPPLIER_ID = ss.ID
    GROUP BY opr.id_order, opr.id_product, ss.id_supplier_ekuep, ss.id_supplier_qava
)

SELECT 
    wbd.waybill_id, 
    sup.waybill_no,
    sup.supplier_id_qava, 
    supq.supplier_qava, 
    supq.supllier_city_qava, 
    supq.supplier_qava_add,
    sup.supplier_id_ekuep, 
    supc.supplier_ekuep, 
    supc.supllier_city_ekuep, 
    supc.supplier_ekuep_add
FROM waybill_products AS wbd
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        wb.waybill_id,
        ow.waybill_no,
        CASE 
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_qava = 1 THEN '1'
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_qava = 0 THEN op.ID_Supplier_Qava
            ELSE NULL 
        end as supplier_id_qava,
        case 
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_ekuep = 1 THEN '1'
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_ekuep = 0 THEN op.ID_Supplier_Ekuep
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS supplier_id_ekuep
    FROM waybill_products AS wb
    LEFT JOIN ob_cte AS ow 
        ON wb.waybill_id = ow.id
    LEFT JOIN op_etc AS op 
        ON op.id_product = wb.product_id 
            AND op.id_order = ow.order_id
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    left join (
        select 
            wb.WAYBILL_ID, 
            ow.WAYBILL_NO,
            (count(distinct op.ID_Supplier_Qava) > 1)::int as multi_supp_qava,
            (count(distinct op.ID_Supplier_Ekuep) > 1)::int as multi_supp_ekuep
        from WAYBILL_PRODUCTS wb
        LEFT JOIN ob_cte AS ow
            ON wb.waybill_id = ow.id
        left join op_etc AS op 
            on op.ID_PRODUCT = wb.PRODUCT_ID 
                and op.ID_ORDER = ow.ORDER_ID
        where _FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
        group by wb.WAYBILL_ID, ow.WAYBILL_NO
    ) AS mult 
        on mult.WAYBILL_NO = ow.WAYBILL_NO
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    group by wb.WAYBILL_ID, ow.WAYBILL_NO, mult.multi_supp_qava, mult.multi_supp_ekuep, op.ID_Supplier_Qava, op.ID_Supplier_Ekuep
) AS sup 
    on wbd.WAYBILL_ID = sup.WAYBILL_ID
left join (
    select 
        ps.id_supplier                  AS id_supplier_qava,
        ps.name                         AS supplier_qava,
        ps.date_add                     AS supplier_qava_add,
        LISTAGG(DISTINCT pa.CITY, ', ') AS supllier_city_qava
    from QAVASHOP_KSA_QAVAISH_MAINSHOP.PS_SUPPLIER ps
    left join (
        select * 
        from QAVASHOP_KSA_QAVAISH_MAINSHOP.PS_ADDRESS
    ) pa 
        ON pa.ID_SUPPLIER = ps.ID_SUPPLIER 
            AND pa._fivetran_deleted = 0
    WHERE ps.USED_SUPPLIER_ID is null 
        AND ps._fivetran_deleted = 0
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
) AS supq 
    on supq.ID_Supplier_Qava = sup.Supplier_ID_Qava
left join (
    select 
        ps.id_supplier                  AS id_supplier_ekuep,
        ps.name                         AS supplier_ekuep,
        ps.date_add                     AS supplier_ekuep_add,
        LISTAGG(DISTINCT pa.CITY, ', ') AS supllier_city_ekuep
    FROM ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier AS ps
    LEFT JOIN FROM ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_address AS pa 
        ON pa.id_supplier = ps.id_supplier 
            and pa._fivetran_deleted = 0
    WHERE ps.used_supplier_id IS NULL 
        and ps._fivetran_deleted = 0
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 4
) AS supc 
    ON supc.id_supplier_ekuep = sup.supplier_id_ekuep
WHERE _fivetran_deleted = 0
GROUP BY wbd.waybill_id, sup.waybill_no,
       sup.supplier_id_qava, supq.supplier_qava, 
       supq.supllier_city_qava, supq.supplier_qava_add,
       sup.supplier_id_ekuep, supc.supplier_ekuep, 
       supc.supllier_city_ekuep, supc.supplier_ekuep_add;
```

Now `op_etc` itself, that `GROUP BY` at the end is really just a DISTINCT so we can swap that in. Also in `ss` of that `op_cte`

```
        SELECT 
            s.id, 
            supc.id_supplier_ekuep, 
            supq.id_supplier_qava
        FROM suppliers AS s
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id_supplier AS id_supplier_ekuep
            FROM ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier 
            WHERE used_supplier_id IS NULL
        ) AS supc 
            ON supc.id_supplier_ekuep = s.id_supplier 
                AND s.store_id = 1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id_supplier AS id_supplier_qava
            FROM qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_supplier 
            WHERE used_supplier_id IS NULL
        ) AS supq 
            ON supq.id_supplier_qava = s.id_supplier
                AND s.store_id = 2
```

those to left joins, keep only values that are NULL and then LEFT JOIN of two requirements which means we are get a row per suppliers the IS NULL can be moved to the ON with no impact, which means the rename can be moved higher up, and the sub-select dropped, so that section can become:

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    supc.id_supplier AS id_supplier_ekuep, 
    supq.id_supplier AS id_supplier_qava
FROM suppliers AS s
LEFT JOIN ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier AS supc 
    ON supc.id_supplier = s.id_supplier 
        AND s.store_id = 1 
        AND supc.used_supplier_id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_supplier AS supq 
    ON supq.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
        AND s.store_id = 2 
        AND supq.used_supplier_id IS NULL
```

thus the `op_cte` becomes:

```
), op_etc AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        opr.id_order,
        opr.id_product,
        ss.id_supplier_ekuep,
        ss.id_supplier_qava
    FROM order_products AS opr
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            s.id, 
            supc.id_supplier AS id_supplier_ekuep, 
            supq.id_supplier AS id_supplier_qava
        FROM suppliers AS s
        LEFT JOIN ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier AS supc 
            ON supc.id_supplier = s.id_supplier 
                AND s.store_id = 1 
                AND supc.used_supplier_id IS NULL
        LEFT JOIN qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_supplier AS supq 
            ON supq.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
                AND s.store_id = 2 
                AND supq.used_supplier_id IS NULL
    ) AS ss 
        ON opr.SUPPLIER_ID = ss.ID
)
```

which actually means the `ss` can just be left joined as first order things like:

```
), op_etc AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        opr.id_order,
        opr.id_product,
        supc.id_supplier AS id_supplier_ekuep,
        supq.id_supplier AS id_supplier_qava
    FROM order_products AS opr
    LEFT JOIN suppliers AS s
        opr.SUPPLIER_ID = s.ID
    LEFT JOIN ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier AS supc 
        ON supc.id_supplier = s.id_supplier 
            AND s.store_id = 1 
            AND supc.used_supplier_id IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_supplier AS supq 
        ON supq.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
            AND s.store_id = 2 
            AND supq.used_supplier_id IS NULL
)
```

ah thats much more refreshing..

in `the sub-select` sup` I am worried, that you are grouping by values that are not in you output set, so you will get duplicate rows

in this case block

```
CASE 
    WHEN mult.multi_supp_qava = 1 THEN '1'
    WHEN mult.multi_supp_qava = 0 THEN op.ID_Supplier_Qava
    ELSE NULL 
end as supplier_id_qava,
```

you are group not by the output `supplier_id_qava` or it's position `3` but `mult.multi_supp_qava, op.ID_Supplier_Qava`

so if `op.ID_Supplier_Qava` is not null when `mult.multi_supp_qava = 1` and can have different values, the supplier_id_qava will output 1 on both rows, but they will not merge, as `op.ID_Supplier_Qava` is different. This is the root of my strong dislike for using the input to the SELECT section as the grouping clauses of the aggregation of those values. because through transformation, they can become the same on the output, but remain different on the input, and produce hard to debug deuplicates. And if the flip case that they are alway safe/null/constant in the odd case, this is not clear to the SQL reader. (on this point I have to say a strong thank you for have used the aliases on select etc, as that alway confidance of where those values are coming from).

So again the GROUP BY on `sup` has no agration of values so this is a hidden DISTINCT, but it not giving distinct values *perhaps* in all cases.

So after moving some sub-selects into CTE's as I find it makes each select layer show, just what it is doing, with have to leap over smaller details we get SQL like this:

```
WITH ob_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        order_id, 
        waybill_no 
    FROM order_waybills
), op_etc AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        opr.id_order,
        opr.id_product,
        supc.id_supplier AS id_supplier_ekuep,
        supq.id_supplier AS id_supplier_qava
    FROM order_products AS opr
    LEFT JOIN suppliers AS s
        opr.SUPPLIER_ID = s.ID
    LEFT JOIN ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier AS supc 
        ON supc.id_supplier = s.id_supplier 
            AND s.store_id = 1 
            AND supc.used_supplier_id IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_supplier AS supq 
        ON supq.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
            AND s.store_id = 2 
            AND supq.used_supplier_id IS NULL
), mult_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        wb.waybill_id, 
        ow.waybill_no,
        (COUNT(DISTINCT op.id_supplier_qava) > 1)::int AS multi_supp_qava,
        (COUNT(DISTINCT op.id_supplier_ekuep) > 1)::int AS multi_supp_ekuep
    FROM waybill_products AS wb
    LEFT JOIN ob_cte AS ow
        ON wb.waybill_id = ow.id
    LEFT JOIN op_etc AS op 
        ON op.id_product = wb.product_id 
            AND op.id_order = ow.order_id
    WHERE _fivetran_deleted = 0
    GROUP BY wb.waybill_id, ow.waybill_no
), supq_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        ps.id_supplier                  AS id_supplier_qava,
        ps.name                         AS supplier_qava,
        ps.date_add                     AS supplier_qava_add,
        LISTAGG(DISTINCT pa.city, ', ') AS supllier_city_qava
    FROM qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_supplier AS ps
    LEFT JOIN qavashop_ksa_qavaish_mainshop.ps_address AS pa 
        ON pa.id_supplier = ps.id_supplier 
            AND pa._fivetran_deleted = 0
    WHERE ps.used_supplier_id is null 
        AND ps._fivetran_deleted = 0
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
), supc_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        ps.id_supplier                  AS id_supplier_ekuep,
        ps.name                         AS supplier_ekuep,
        ps.date_add                     AS supplier_ekuep_add,
        LISTAGG(DISTINCT pa.city, ', ') AS supllier_city_ekuep
    FROM ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_supplier AS ps
    LEFT JOIN FROM ekuep_ksa_ekuep_staging.ps_address AS pa 
        ON pa.id_supplier = ps.id_supplier 
            AND pa._fivetran_deleted = 0
    WHERE ps.used_supplier_id IS NULL 
        AND ps._fivetran_deleted = 0
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 4
), sup_cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        wb.waybill_id,
        ow.waybill_no,
        CASE 
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_qava = 1 THEN '1'
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_qava = 0 THEN op.ID_Supplier_Qava
            ELSE NULL 
        end as supplier_id_qava,
        case 
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_ekuep = 1 THEN '1'
            WHEN mult.multi_supp_ekuep = 0 THEN op.ID_Supplier_Ekuep
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS supplier_id_ekuep
    FROM waybill_products AS wb
    LEFT JOIN ob_cte AS ow 
        ON wb.waybill_id = ow.id
    LEFT JOIN op_etc AS op 
        ON op.id_product = wb.product_id 
            AND op.id_order = ow.order_id
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LEFT JOIN mult_cte AS mult 
        on mult.WAYBILL_NO = ow.WAYBILL_NO
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)

SELECT 
    wbd.waybill_id, 
    sup.waybill_no,
    sup.supplier_id_qava, 
    supq.supplier_qava, 
    supq.supllier_city_qava, 
    supq.supplier_qava_add,
    sup.supplier_id_ekuep, 
    supc.supplier_ekuep, 
    supc.supllier_city_ekuep, 
    supc.supplier_ekuep_add
FROM waybill_products AS wbd
LEFT JOIN sup_cte AS sup 
    ON wbd.WAYBILL_ID = sup.WAYBILL_ID
LEFT JOIN supq_cte AS supq 
    ON supq.id_supplier_qava = sup.supplier_id_qava
LEFT JOIN supc_cte AS supc 
    ON supc.id_supplier_ekuep = sup.supplier_id_ekuep
WHERE _fivetran_deleted = 0
GROUP BY wbd.waybill_id, sup.waybill_no,
       sup.supplier_id_qava, supq.supplier_qava, 
       supq.supllier_city_qava, supq.supplier_qava_add,
       sup.supplier_id_ekuep, supc.supplier_ekuep, 
       supc.supllier_city_ekuep, supc.supplier_ekuep_add;
```

And at the end we see again you are suffering from duplicate data, that you are trying to clean away with yet another GROUP BY.. so we will switch to a DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    wbd.waybill_id, 
    sup.waybill_no,
    sup.supplier_id_qava, 
    supq.supplier_qava, 
    supq.supllier_city_qava, 
    supq.supplier_qava_add,
    sup.supplier_id_ekuep, 
    supc.supplier_ekuep, 
    supc.supllier_city_ekuep, 
    supc.supplier_ekuep_add
FROM waybill_products AS wbd
LEFT JOIN sup_cte AS sup 
    ON wbd.WAYBILL_ID = sup.WAYBILL_ID
LEFT JOIN supq_cte AS supq 
    ON supq.id_supplier_qava = sup.supplier_id_qava
LEFT JOIN supc_cte AS supc 
    ON supc.id_supplier_ekuep = sup.supplier_id_ekuep
WHERE _fivetran_deleted = 0
```

### Right so what was your question again?

you want to get rid of all the nulls... if this is so "why so many left joins" or returning null from CASE statements..

Right so in the picture to show a `waybill_no` with values, and another where `supplier_id_qava` is null, given the later comes from

```
LEFT JOIN sup_cte AS sup 
    ON wbd.WAYBILL_ID = sup.WAYBILL_ID
```

and everything else connect via `sup` you should change that from a `LEFT JOIN` to just a `JOIN`

Comment: This is beyond perfection - thank you so much. Now it's not just I solved the problem, I even understood my mistake and how it should be. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Nabaa if it helped Accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I did - sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH data(num, id) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
      (2559,    23),
      (2559,    33),
      (2559,    55),
      (2550,    89),
      (2499,    14),
      (2499,    14)
)
SELECT 
    num,
    id,
    count(*) over(partition by num) as num_dup,
    count(distinct id)over(partition by num) as id_dup,
    iff(num_dup > 1 AND num_dup = id_dup, 1, 0) as "check"
FROM data;
```

gives:

| NUM | ID | NUM_DUP | ID_DUP | check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2559 | 23 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 2559 | 33 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 2559 | 55 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 2550 | 89 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2499 | 14 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2499 | 14 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

### Extra Data:

```
WITH data(num, id) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
      (2559,    23),
      (2559,    33),
      (2559,    33),
      (2559,    55),
      (2550,    89),
      (2499,    14),
      (2499,    14)
)
SELECT 
    num,
    id,
    count(*) over(partition by num) as num_dup,
    count(distinct id)over(partition by num) as id_dup,
    iff(num_dup > 1 AND num_dup = id_dup, 1, 0) as "check"
FROM data;
```

if we make `2559` have two `33`'s then it show change to 0/false

| NUM | ID | NUM_DUP | ID_DUP | check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2559 | 23 | 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 2559 | 33 | 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 2559 | 33 | 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 2559 | 55 | 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 2550 | 89 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2499 | 14 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2499 | 14 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

### Last Step:

```
WITH data(num, id) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
      (2559,    23),
      (2559,    33),
      (2559,    55),
      (2550,    89),
      (2499,    14),
      (2499,    14)
)
SELECT 
    num,
    iff(count(*) > 1 AND count(*) = count(distinct id), 1, 0) as output
FROM data
GROUP BY 1;
```

gives:

| NUM | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| 2559 | 1 |
| 2550 | 0 |
| 2499 | 0 |

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - I would like also to be able to remove (Number) rows if the values were nulls. 
For example, if column (Number) had the values 2559 and 2559 and column (ID) had the values 23 and null. 
I would like to keep 23 and ignore the row containing the null, is that possible?

Comment: @Nabaa so if you have the data ` (2499,    14), (2499,    15)` this would be a `1` as it has more than 1 2499 and count(distinct id) = count(*), but if you have the data ` (2499, 14),
      (2499,    15), (2499, null) ` it becomes a zero as the count of id = 2 but the count of the numer is 3. So the question is do you want to not count of ether side?

Comment: this can be done by flipping to count just id's with: `iff(count(id) > 1 AND count(id) = count(distinct id), 1, 0) as output`

Comment: I've edited the original post to explain further more the case I am facing, also I've posted the code along with the output I am getting. Hope its more clear now.